# How do I say "I am going to go to" in spanish?

Tags: gramática

I am using [English to spanish translater](http://spanishdict.com) to convert the following sentence into Spanish :

```
I am going to go to Guatemala.
```

Translater Response :

```
 Voy a ir a Guatemala.
```

Does it make sense in spanish? Or is there any other way to say "I am going to go to" in spanish?

Gracias!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Makes perfect sense.

We often use ***voy a ir*** to add emphasis.
***Voy a...*** also makes sense.
So either way it's correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use *Me iré a Guatemala*, which is the future form of *to go* if you want to avoid the double *or* (just like English switching *going to go* to *will go*)

Answer (score 0):

Voy a ir a Guatemala o Me voy a ir a Guatemala, both are correct.